# How to create a folder using a name based on the current date in Powershell?

Tags: datetime, powershell, create-directory

I have around 50 xml files that are newly generated everytime I run a particular logic. Now I want these 50 files to be stored inside a particular date-time folder. No matter how many times ever I run that logic for one particular date, the xml files should be overwritten for that particular date only (based on the hhmmss). In simple , How to create a folder using a name based on the current date and store the xml files in them depending on the date?

For Eg: there are 3 xml files
file_1.xml, file_2.xml and file_3.xml

Now I want a folder to be created in the format-

```
**xml_yyyymmdd_hhmmss**
```

that would house all the xml files in them.

```
For Eg: Xml_20121029_180912
```

would be the folder created for today's date. And all the 3 xml files will be stored in this for today.

For tomorrow the folder name would be:

```
Xml_20121030_170912
```

My code looks like below:

```
$location = New-Item -Path . -ItemType Directory -Name ("XML_$(Get-Date -f dd_MM_yyyy_hhmmss)")
$rptdir = "C:\Test" 
$ rptdir = ($rptdir + '\' + $location.Name)
$outputFile= "$rptdir\File_2.xml"
$row = "\\shared\Data\DevSB\CS\appSomeSystem.dll"   
& /f:$row /o:$outputFile
```

**Output Error**: Could not find part of the path "C:\test\XML_29_10_2012_091717\File2.xml.

The **issue** here is- The folder XML_29_10_2012_091717 is created with File2.xml in it but not inside the C:\Test but where the script is.

**I need XML_29_10_2012_091717 to be created in C:\test with File2.xml inside it.**

**Environment**: Win Xp Professional.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
New-Item -Path . -ItemType Directory -Name ("XML_$(Get-Date -f ddMMyyyy_hhmmss)")
```

Edit after comments:

try changing this:

```
$location = New-Item -Path c:\test -ItemType Directory -Name ("XML_$(Get-Date -f dd_MM_yyyy_hhmmss)")
$outputFile= "$($location.fullname)\File_2.xml"
```

Comment: This kinda works..but, I have $rptDir = "C:\Test". When I assign the above to a variable say $xmlLoc = New-Item -Path . -ItemType Directory -Name ("XML_$(Get-Date -f ddMMyyyy_hhmmss)") and I append $xmlLoc to "C:\Test\$xmlLoc" it says given path's format is not supported. How can I append it?

Comment: @ashishg How are you append it? try `($rptdir + '\' + $xmlLoc.Name )`. It return a string with full path

Comment: I tried - $rptDir = "C:\Test" + '\' + Location.Name and the variable which I am setting for the output of the xml file is $outputFile = $rptDir\File1.xml" but still the same error. And also, in this case the xml datetime folder is created (without the xml file File1.xml in it) in the folder where the script actually is and not in $rptDir.

Comment: I have around 50 xml files to be stored in the datetime folder for the current date. If I try to loop in 50 files.. a new folder is getting created every minute which is inevitable. But after removing the time part (hhmmsss part) from the folder the current date folder is created but after the very first time, each time it loops through to input the xml file i get the error - xml folder already exists and it fails to write the xml file into it.

Comment: One last thing here.. What if I need to read these Xml files created inside the date folder and do a csv out of them? I have a logic wherein it would read a specific attribute in the xmls and print the csv out of them. Any clue? Thanks Again. :)

Comment: @ashishg I suggest to post a new question with all the details.

Comment: There is a strange issue here.. Today I ran the code again and it successfully created a date folder (Xml_2012_10_31) with all the xml files in it, but **it deleted yesterday's folder (Xml_2012_10_30)** from the $rptdir path. How can I ensure that the previous folders remain intact?

Comment: @ashishg without seeing the full code I can help you more of this. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The full version is:

```
New-Item -Path . -ItemType Directory -Name (Get-Date -f dd_MM_yyyy)
```

You can also use md or mkdir

```
md (Get-Date -f dd_MM_yyyy)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$location = New-Item -Path $rptdir -ItemType Directory **-force** -Name ("XML_$(Get-Date -f dd_MM_yyyy_hhmmss)")
```

How about adding a -force cmd-let here?