# How to read xml files stored in a current date folder?

Tags: powershell, directory, datetime-format

I have xml files stored in the current date folder as in here - [Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118883/how-to-create-a-folder-using-a-name-based-on-the-current-date-in-powershell) 
Now I want to read a specific part of the xml and print that in a csv file. 
As in the link How can I use the $location as input to read the xml files based on the current date folder only?

I tried using:

```
$locatexml = -item -path $rptdir -itemtype Directory -Name ("XML_$(Get-Date -f yyyy_mm_dd)")
```

But I get an error - Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
**how can I assign the current folder to $locatexml?** so that I can be able to refer to all the xml files that exist for the current date folder?

My code which is trying to read the xml files located in the date folder:

Removed -itemtype from the $locatexml, I am assigning the fullname to another variable $locatexml2.

```
$locatexml = get-item -path $reportdir -Name ("XML_$(Get-Date -f yyyy_MM_dd)")
**Do I need $locatexml2 here?**
$locatexml2 = "$($location.fullname)" 

Function DoRpt($locatexml2)
{
$rptOut="Asm"
Get-ChildItem  $locatexml2 | ForEach-Object {        
$file = Get-Content -path $locatexml2\$_ -totalcount 15
try {
$asm = [regex]::matches($file[5], 'asm=".*" ')[0].value -replace 'asm="(.*)" ','$1' 
      $rptOut=$rptOut+"`n$Asm,$locatexml2\$_"        
} catch {}   
}
Set-Content -path $testdir\test.csv -value $rptOut
}
```

The XML looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Rpt Version="10.0">
<Targets>
<Target="\\Shared\Data\SB\app\bin\test.dll">
<Mods>
<Mod="test.dll" asm="1.0.0000.000">
</Mod>
</Mods>
</Target>
</Targets>
</Rpt>
```

**I tried all the methods of assigning the $locatexml as metnioned below, but I am not getting through.. Is there something I am missing in the above code?**

DO I really need $locatexml2 here?

Thanks!

Comment: `-item` ? maybe is `get-item` ?

Comment: if I use Get-Item I get the error: get-Item: a paramater cannot be found that matches parameter name item-type. Also as it tries to index the xml files stored in the current date folder, i get the folder access denied error.. do I need to set some permissions here?

Comment: You don't need the `-ItemType` switch with `Get-Item` or `Get-ChildItem`. It's being used with `New-Item` to specify what kind of item you are going to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `dir` in the parent directory, indicating the folder name you are looking for.  I am assuming `$rptdir` is a string indicating the parent directory where the date-named subdirectories reside.

```
$locatexml = dir -Path $rptdir -Filter "XML_$(Get-Date -f yyyy_MM_dd)"
```

Comment: Just need to add $loc2 = "$($locatexml.fullname)" and use this variable $loc2 in the code :) It will work. Thanks Latkin:)

Comment: Also, How can I pass any date as a parameter? so that if someone is interested in browsing through yesterday's folder.. is it possible?

Comment: You just need to put that DateTime object in a variable, and use that variable in the `-Filter` parameter value.  `$someDate = [DateTime] '7/4/2000'` then `-Filter "XML_$($someDate.ToString('yyyy_MM_dd'))"`

Answer (score 0):

This will assign the Directory object to $locationxml where folder name in $rptdir matches `yyyy_MM_dd`:

```
$locationxml = $rptdir | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq (Get-Date -f yyyy_MM_dd)}
```

*Note that date format string... **use uppercase MM to get Month** (your example syntax in problem had lowercase mm which would give you the Minutes).*